# Are all Monad instances in Haskell just different ways for mapping from Hask to Hask?

Tags: haskell, monads, category-theory

I'm reading [Haskell/Category theory](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory) and here is the [definition of monad](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Category_theory#Monads) from that article:

> A monad is a special type of functor, from a category to that same
> category, that supports some additional structure. So, down to
> definitions. A monad is a functor ***M:C->C***, along with two
> morphisms for every **object X in C**:
>
> unit: X -> M(X)
>
> join: M(M(X)) -> M(X)

As I understand it, in Haskell `return` is equivalent to `unit`. But with `return` I can write:

```
x :: [Int]  -- x is a member of Lst category
x = return 5
```

and this is valid code in Haskell.
Now, as you can see, `5` here is not a member of `Lst`, but `return` works for it.

So, I guess that `Lst` is not **С** from **M:C->C**. But who then?

Maybe the right answer is `Hask`, but I'm not sure that "*functor from a category to its subcategory*" is the same as "*functor from a category to the same category*".

Comment: It's from "Haskell/Categry theory": "The main category we'll be concerning ourselves with in this article is Hask, which treats Haskell types as objects and Haskell functions as morphisms ..."

Comment: The `M : C -> C` corresponds to `m` in `class Monad m where ..` , and `C` is the category `Hask`, but in the context `.. : C -> C`, `C` is referring to an object of `C`, which in this case is a type. I suppose it is 'more correct' to write `M : Obj(C) -> Obj(C)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common point of confusion and you've asked the question clearly enough for it to be answerable.

> I'm not sure that "*functor from category to it's subcategory*" is the same as "*functor from category to the same category*".

It's not the same. A functor consists of four pieces of data: a source category C, a target category D, a mapping of objects of C to objects of D, and a mapping of morphisms of C to morphisms of D, satisfying some conditions. If you change D, then you change the functor.

However when we define a functor, we often have some choice in the category D. I infer from your question that `Lst` is a subcategory of `Hask` whose objects are types of the form `[a]`, though I'm not sure what the morphisms of `Lst` are supposed to be. We could define a functor `[]` of either of these two shapes:

1. `[]` : `Hask` -> `Lst` (i.e., the target category of `[]` is `Lst`)
2. `[]` : `Hask` -> `Hask` (i.e., the target category of `[]` is `Hask`)

These are technically different functors, and we have to make a choice. In this context, the correct choice is choice 2. We need the source and target categories to be the same because we need to apply `[]` to the output of `[]`, in `join`. So **C** = `Hask` and **M** = `[]`.

In general, it turns out to rarely be useful to consider categories like `Lst` that are defined as the image of some type constructor. I'm not sure where this (very common) idea comes from. I recommend you set aside the idea of "the category `Lst`". Just one category is enough for now!

For an analogy consider the function that squares a real number f(x) = x^2. We can view this as a function f : R -> R from the real numbers to the real numbers, even though it so happens that f(x) only takes on nonnegative real values. The target of f does not have to be equal to the image of f (the values that are actually attained by f on its input values).

Comment: Thank you, your answer is very helpful!

Answer (score 0):

A monad is, by definition, an endofunctor. The typeclass `Functor` is really represents endofunctors, as instances of `Functor` are defined for type constructors, which are type-level functions which take a type and return a new type (that is, they have kind `* -> *`).

`return :: Monad m => a -> m a`, so it is not surprising that `return` can take a value of type `Int` and return a value of type `[Int]`.